# Conversion from pairwise matrix to Cytoscape edge table is too slow

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, cytoscape

My code is similar to [this](https://www.biostars.org/p/80498/#80502).
Given a matrix like this:

```
  a  b  c  d
a 1  NA 3  4
b NA 2  NA 4
c NA NA NA NA
d NA NA NA 4
```

It converts it to this:

```
a  a  1
a  c  3
a  d  4
b  b  2
b  d  4
d  d  4
```

The relevant code is as below:

```
  2 pears <- read.delim("pears.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".")
  3 edges <- NULL
  4 for (i in 1:nrow(pears)) {
  5         for (j in 1:ncol(pears)) {
  6                 if (!(is.na(pears[i,j]))) {
  7                         edges <- rbind(edges, c(rownames(pears)[i], colnames(pears)[j], pears[i,j]))
  8                 }
  9         }
 10         print(i)
 11 }
 12 colnames(edges) <- c("gene1", "gene2", "PCC")
 13 write.table(edges, "edges.txt", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

When I run the code from a remote server in the background using `screen -S` on a 17804x17804 sparse (99% NA) matrix, it initially runs 5 print statements every 13 seconds. However, it has now slowed down to 7 print statements every minute. Why is the algorithm getting slower and slower as it progresses? Is there another way I can convert my matrix into a Cytoscape's format quicker?

Comment: Try with `library(reshape2); subset(melt(as.matrix(df1)), !is.na(value))`

Comment: This worked, thank you. If anyone else is looking at this and is also running code remotely, make sure you explicitly set the `lib` param of install.packages and `lib.loc` param of library if you can't write to the site-packages directory on the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the data.frame to `matrix`, use `melt` from `reshape2` to get the dimnames as two columns along with the values as third column, then `subset` while using `na.rm` to remove the NA rows

```
library(reshape2)
melt(as.matrix(df1), na.rm = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, NA, NA, NA), b = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA), 
c = c(3L, NA, NA, NA), d = c(4L, 4L, NA, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c("a", 
  "b", "c", "d"))
```